# Capistrano deploy with bitbucket - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

After adding public key to `bitbucket` acct, `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` returns (in windows):

```
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (131.103.20.167)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 65:8c:1b:f2:6f:91:6b:5c:3b:ec:4a:46:46:74:7z:40.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
logged in as myusername.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

We verified that `bitbucket.org` has been added to `known_hosts`. The `cap deploy` command returns:

```
Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

We added the following 2 lines to `deploy.rb` file:

```
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```

Now `cap deploy` returns error:

```
 Permission denied (publickey).
```

Keys are not passphrase protected. If the key is accepted by `bitbucket`(`ssh -T` returns right info), why we still have the error of `Permission denied`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you run the `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` command on the remote server, and confirmed it there? I've just checked a Linux server I deploy onto with Capistrano, and bitbucket.org is listed in the deploying user's .ssh/known_hosts files (it's hashed, but `ssh-keygen -F bitbucket.org` shows it).

Capistrano SSHes into the remote server, and runs the git checkout from there. It needs permission to connect to Bitbucket, although the access is granted from the source machine, via the `:forward_agent` option.

Comment: `@Alister Bulman`, `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` returns `permission denied` on remote server and you are right about it. Do we need to add keys on remote server and add its private key to bitbucket?

Comment: You just need to confirm the authenticity of the host - it may well fail because you aren't forwarding the keys on a simple SSH login, but then it should do better with Capistrano and a forwarded agent.

Comment: Just did and it works great. I did not realize that bitbucket required authentication of remote server in addition to the deploying PC (github only require authentication of deploying PC).  Thanks again!