# Capistrano and Bitbucket Deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ssh, capistrano, bitbucket

Using Capistrano version 3.4.0

1. I have created a ssh key on my centos 7 server
2. I have set that ssh key on bitbucket
3. repo url set as follows on my deploy.rb file :

   set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:Username/myProjectName.git'
4. on my production.rb file:

   role :myProjectName, %w{Username@131.103.20.167}

   set :ssh_options, {
       auth_methods: %w(password),
       password: "mybitbucketpasswordhere"
   }
5. i checked if i can login with my username with `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` command:

   logged in as Username.
6. cap production deploy in my project folder and i get following error :

   INFO [90fbd4ee] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/myProjectName/ as Username@131.103.20.167
   DEBUG [90fbd4ee] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/myProjectName/
   (Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
   cap aborted!
   Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user Username@131.103.20.167

   Tasks: TOP => git:check => git:wrapper
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
   The deploy has failed with an error: Authentication failed for user Username@131.103.20.167

Where do i go wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've added your SSH Key, which should mean you don't need to provide a password. So this line: `set :ssh_options, { auth_methods: %w(password), password: "mybitbucketpasswordhere" }` is incorrect.

I believe the default for capistrano is to use SSH authentication, so try just removing that line.

Comment: i removed the line, write the file, double checked but i get the same error.

Comment: When you're SSH'd into your server, can you git clone your project without having to enter a password (ie, using ssh key authentication)?

Comment: yes, you're right but i tried that already. Where should i check more ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean there? Can you ssh in to your sever and git clone your project without having to enter a password? Or does that give you an error?

Comment: i'm having the error : Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user Username@131.103.20.167

Comment: "cap production deploy" command. I set my settings from here btw: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/deploying-a-laravel-application-using-capistrano--net-35685

Comment: Don't do "cap production deploy". Forget about capistrano for now, we just want to SSH into your sever manually (ssh your_user@your_host) and then see if you can git clone the project from bitbucket onto your server, manually. Does that make sense?

Comment: okay. on terminal i tried this one : ssh myusername@131.103.20.167 and got this : Permission denied (publickey) that is the bitbucket's ip number. I found a post about it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782622/capistrano-deploy-with-bitbucket-permission-denied-publickey but cannot clearly understand.

Comment: So at this point we're not trying to ssh in to bitbucket. We're trying to SSH into the CentOS 7 server that you set up. First, ensure you can SSH into that Centos 7 server. Then, verify that you can git clone your project from Bitbucket, down to your CentOS 7 server, while you are logged in to your CentOS 7 server. 

Once that's working fine, you can move on to get capistrano working.

Comment: Thanks for the help. After i'm done i'll mark that as an answer.